# how to move turtle randomly on patch

Tags: netlogo

I have a simple situation where I have each patch sprout a turtle. The size of my turtle is 0.5, so I can see the patch on which the turtle is.

I'd like to have the turtle randomly move on the patch without ever leave it. Is there any primitive to check a turtle is moving but not leaving a patch?

Comment: There is no specific primitive (unless you count `patch-here`) but the turtle coordinates and patch coordinates use the same coordinate system. These are explained in the tutorial #1 on the NetLogo site.

Comment: There is no edit to the question, 1 tag from the very beginning.. what are you saying @developernator ?

Comment: @JenB write that as answer, happy to accept

Comment: done. hope it helps. If you can't make it work, post some relevant code and a description of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific primitive (unless you count `patch-here`) but the turtle coordinates and patch coordinates use the same coordinate system. These are explained in the tutorial #1 on the NetLogo site. For example, a turtle at with `xcor` of -0.4 and `ycor` of 10.2 will be on the patch 0 10.